# How do I access a String from another method?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Pokémon type of game to test out my novice coding skills. But I have run into a bit of a problem.

If I run the program as it stands, I will get a window that pops up with the 2 attacks (Tackle and Thunder Shock). Tackle works when I click once, but Thunder Shock needs to be clicked twice; I'm guessing this is because `pikaAtkType()` is used in both if's.

I need to compare the "picked" string from the method to the message box to have it work properly.

My question being, how do I access "picked" from the `pikaAtkType()` method and put it into the if statements so I can compare the message box inputs without having to press "OK" twice for Thunder Shock. (I would like to do this in a simple way; I'm not the best at coding.)

```
if (Encounter().equals("Attack")) {
    if (pikaAtkType().equals("Tackle")) {
        pikaDMG = 3;
    } else if (pikaAtkType().equals("Thunder Shock")) {
        pikaDMG = 4;
    }
}
```

The method `pikaAtkType()` (remember these are just pieces of the code):

```
static String pikaAtkType() {
    String[] choices = {"Tackle", "Thunder Shock", "", ""};
    String picked = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        null,
        "Select Attack: ",
        "Attack!",
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
        null,
        choices,
        choices[0]);
    return picked;
}
```

Comment: You can't, you have to figure out some other way. Check [class fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, one solution is to get the "attack" once and store it in a local variable. Something like,

```
if (Encounter ().equals ("Attack"))
{
  String attack = pikaAtkType (); 
  if (attack.equals ("Tackle"))
  {
    pikaDMG = 3;
  }
  else if (attack.equals ("Thunder Shock"))
  {
    pikaDMG = 4;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a field in your class that equals picked

```
public class Pokemon {
    String picked = "";

    static void pikaAtkType ()
    {

        String[] choices = {"Tackle", "Thunder Shock", "", ""};
        String picked = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Select Attack: ", "Attack!",     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, choices, choices [0]);
        this.picked = picked;
    }
}
```

Then you just simply go:

```
if (Encounter ().equals ("Attack")) {
    pickAtkType();
    if (picked.equals ("Tackle"))
    {
    pikaDMG = 3;
    }
    else if (picked.equals ("Thunder Shock"))
    {
    pikaDMG = 4;
    }
```